# Pasar item de un Listbox a un Label

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un programa que tiene un Listbox1 en Form1, y quiero que al presionar el botón Modificar, se cierre el formulario y el item Id pase a un Label1 en Form2.

He intentado usar el Userform_Load pero no sé como asignarle la fila seleccionada del Listbox1.

También he intando el siguiente

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Integer
'obtengo el index que esta seleccionado
i = HistorialTickets.lstTicketsProblemas.SelectedIndex

'le paso el valor de item
lblCorrelativoTk.Text = HistorialTickets.lstTicketsProblemas.Items(i).Text

End Sub

y me sale error de método o no encuentra dato miembro.

A la espera de sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta haciendo lo siguiente:
En el formulario 2 declara una variable publica, por ejemplo 
Public dato As String

Luego en el botón modificar del formulario 1 pones lo siguiente:
formulario2.dato = tuListBox.Text
formulario2.Show()
Me.Hide()

En el formulario 2 en el evento load pones lo siguiente:
tuLabel.Caption = dato

Comment: Gracias José voy a probar a ver si funciona, lo solucioné quitando el initialize. Saludos,